# Office 365 Excel Online keeps on deleting a textbox

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive, office365

I have a number of spreadsheets on One Drive. If I open them in "Excel Online", the first thing that happens is that the text box which contains the header graphic and title on the spreadsheet is removed, and the spreadsheet is updated, so it no longer exists.

However, if I right click it and open it using the local version of Excel, then the text box and image is there.

Anyone have a clue what is happening here, and how I can stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior, as per the warning message shown when attempting it. Therefore, you must open this file in Excel or the same thing will continue to happen.

[image]

More information is available here: [Edit a workbook that contains features unsupported by Excel Online](http://office.microsoft.com/client/15/help/home?Shownav=true&lcid=1033&ns=XLWAEndUser&ver=15&apps=WDWAENDUSER%2CXLWAENDUSER%2CPPWAENDUSER%2CONWAENDUSER&HelpID=ExcelUnsupported)

Comment: Thanks. Im still on office 2010, so assume that the person in question "Forgot" to mention that they had done that before sayingthat we had given them rubbish software.

Comment: @Matt - You tell us?

Answer (score -1):

You would think that using Excel Online would be the same as using the desktop version of Excel. Imagine being able to design an Excel workbook for a particular use, do all the testing and checking on your desktop and when it works flawlessly, upload to your one drive account to share with your work partners. Unfortunately, the online version of excel is only a basic dumbed down version of excel. No macros, no drop down lists, no objects and many other features of the desktop version are not supported. Until this program has all the features of the desktop version it is useless. Unless you have just a very basic Excel file for viewing and with minimum interaction and editing required.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, your answer only duplicates content from CharlieRB's answer. Each answer is expected to contribute something new to the question, so answer posts that only duplicate existing content are not considered useful and are subject to deletion.  Also, the site is a knowledge base rather than a forum, so we're looking for fact-based answers that avoid commentary.